# Populate tableview in swift

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift, tableview, nstableview

I have this result after parsing XML result.

When I do a `println()` I get the result perfectly like this

```
{
   description = "Suzuki SX4 - BB71521";
   deviceID = 359710042040320;
}
{
   description = "Chevrolet Tahoe Noir - Demonstration";
   deviceID = 359710042067463;
}
{
   description = "Isuzu D'Max AA-08612";
   deviceID = 359710042091273;
}
{
   description = "Toyota 4 Runner";
   deviceID = 359710042110768;
}
```

But when I try to parse the same result in an `UITableView` with two Cells, the `UITableView` appears empty.

Please help me to populate only the table ???

Here is my code

```
import UIKit

class mtTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSXMLParserDelegate {

var info = NSDictionary();
var parser = NSXMLParser()
var posts = NSMutableArray()
var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
var element = NSString()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    self.beginParsing()                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func beginParsing()
{

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8080")
    var auth =

    "<GTSRequest command=\"dbget\">" +
        "<Authorization account=\"" + "easytrucking" + "\" user=\"" + "admin" + "\" password=\"" + "T8095634934ht" + "\"/>" +
        "<Record table=\"Device\" partial=\"true\">" +
        "<Field name=\"accountID\">" + "easytrucking" + "</Field>" +
        "<Field name=\"description\"/>" +           
        "</Record>" +
    "</GTSRequest>";

    //   "<Authorization account=\"" + txtAccount.text + "\" user=\"" + txtUserName.text + "\" password=\"" + txtPassword.text + "\"/>" +

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let data : NSData = (auth).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!;
    request.HTTPBody = data;
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
  /// println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))

      let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data)

        let count = xml["GTSResponse"]["Record"].all.count

        for var i = 0; i < count; i++
        {

            if (xml["GTSResponse"]["Record"][i]["Field"][1].element?.attributes["name"] == "deviceID")
            {

                self.elements.setObject((xml["GTSResponse"]["Record"][i]["Field"][1].element?.text)!, forKey: "deviceID")

            }
            if (xml["GTSResponse"]["Record"][i]["Field"][3].element?.attributes["name"] == "description")
            {
                self.elements.setObject((xml["GTSResponse"]["Record"][i]["Field"][3].element?.text)!, forKey: "description")

            }
            self.posts.addObject(self.elements)

// here i print the result
            println(self.elements)

        } 
    }
}
 //Tableview Methods

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return posts.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell : UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Cell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as UITableViewCell;
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("deviceID") as NSString
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("description") as NSString

    return cell as UITableViewCell
}
}
```

Please help !!!

Comment: Call `tableView.reloadData()` after populating the `posts` array ...

Comment: thank's bro, it works, but it fill the tableview with on the last value four time, for example the tableview populates with only this value during four time : "Toyota 4 Runner"/ "359710042110768";

Comment: thank's bro, it works, but it fill the tableview with on the last value four time, for example the tableview populates with only this value during four time : "Toyota 4 Runner"/ "359710042110768";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems. First, `NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest()`
– as the name indicates – works asynchronously: It initiates a network
request and then returns. The completion handler is called later, when
the data is has arrived. Then you have to reload the table view with

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

after populating the data source array with the new data.

Second, in

```
for var i = 0; i < count; i++
{
    self.elements.setObject(..., forKey: ...)
    self.elements.setObject(..., forKey: ...)
    // ...
    self.posts.addObject(self.elements)
}
```

you are modifying *the same* dictionary again and again. `NSMutableArray`
and `NSMutableDictionary` are reference types, therefore you end up
with an array containing `count` pointers to the same dictionary
(containing the data from the last loop execution).

Instead of a having a single dictionary as property

```
var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
```

this should be a local variable in your loop:

```
for var i = 0; i < count; i++
{
    var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
    self.elements.setObject(..., forKey: ...)
    self.elements.setObject(..., forKey: ...)
    // ...
    self.posts.addObject(elements)
}
```

You might also consider to use Swift arrays and dictionaries instead.
These are *value types* which makes this kind of error much less
likely.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank's ! right now it shows all values, but each values is duplicated, how can i resolve it?

Comment: it's very helpful. Thank's so much